# Android Azure Easy Tables error: incompatible types: MobileServiceTable<RouterTable> cannot be converted to List<RouterTable>

Tags: android, azure

I am trying to incorporate Azure easy tables into my app by following the docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-android-how-to-use-client-library) but I get this list error when trying to query the table.  Please help!

```
try {
            mClient = new MobileServiceClient(
                    "https://azurept.azurewebsites.net",
                    this);

            // Extend timeout from default of 10s to 20s
            mClient.setAndroidHttpClientFactory(new OkHttpClientFactory() {
                @Override
                public OkHttpClient createOkHttpClient() {
                    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                    client.setReadTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                    client.setWriteTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                    return client;
                }
            });

            MobileServiceTable<RouterTable> mRouterTable = mClient.getTable(RouterTable.class);
            List<RouterTable> results = mRouterTable;
            try {
                results = mRouterTable
                        .where()
                        .field("serial").eq(serial)
                        .select("mac")
                        .execute()
                        .get();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.i(TAG, results.get(0).toString());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: the error makes sense to me, but the docs seem to tell me to do it this way?

Comment: I see now what I did wrong - I changed my code to this for the query:

List<RouterTable> results;
        results = mRouterTable
                .where()
                .field("serial").eq(serial)
                .select("mac")
                .execute()
                .get();
        return results.get(0).toString();